# XSLT get child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

how can I get the child nodes from an xslt?
This is how my structure looks like:
``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
    <object>
        <cats>
            <cat>
                <entity_id>1</entity_id>
            </cat>
            <cat>
                <entity_id>2</entity_id>
            </cat>
            <cat>
                <entity_id>10</entity_id>
            </cat>
    </object>
</objects>
```

I've tried
`cats/cat/entity_id`
 but then I only get the first entity_id how can I get the second or third?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer
with `cats/cat[2]/entity_id` I can get the second

Answer (score 0):

The idea to make "enumerative" references to particular instances is
not a good solution.

In XSLT 1.0, if you use e.g. `xsl:value-of` with `select` returning
**mutliple** nodes, then `xsl:value-of` takes **only the first** returned
item and the rest apparently "vanishes".

In order to process the full returned sequence you have to:

- store it in a variable,
- process it in a loop (`for-each`).

This feature has been changed in XSLT 2.0, where:

- **all** returned items are output,
- there is `separator` attribute, stating what to insert
  between consecutive items.